# How to open Popup with database value after saving user's information in database(using asp.net)

Tags: javascript

[I have mention the business detail image with two popups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBonz.png)   I want to display `Popup` with data of that particular businessidafter geting visitors info(name and mobile number).

Here's my Javascript code for popup:

My modal 'Popup` to view data from databse

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#btnclick').click(function () {

            $("#myModal").dialog({

                width: 500,
                height: 200,
                modal: true,

            });
        });
    })

    function openPopup(BusinessContactNo, Email, Website) {
        $('#lblId').text(BusinessContactNo);
        $('#lblName').text(Email);
        $('#lblPrice').text(Website);

        $("#myModal").dialog({
            title: "Business Contact Details",           
            modal: true,

        });

    }
    </script>//popup to display contact details function

exampleModal popup to save data and display mymodal popup with data

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#btnclick').click(function () {
            $("#exampleModal").dialog({
                width: 500,
                height: 200,
                modal: true,

            });
        });
    })

    function openPopup1(UserId) {
        $('#lblUserId').text(UserId);
        $("#Button1").click();   
        $("#exampleModal").dialog({
            title: "Business Contact Details",

            modal: true,

        });

    }

    </script>//popup to save visitor function

businessdirectory.aspx grid of business details-
grid to display basic data
 <asp:GridView ID="gvMemberList" runat="server" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="10" Width="100%"  AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowHeader="false" BorderWidth="0" OnPageIndexChanging="gvProfiles_PageIndexChanging"  HorizontalAlign="NotSet" PagerStyle-Wrap="True">
        <PagerSettings Position="Bottom" Mode="Numeric" />
        <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" Font-Size="Larger" />
        <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemStyle BorderWidth="0"  />
                    <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="recent-posts">                   
                <hr/>
                <div class="recent-posts-info">
                    <div class="postheadback">                           
                        <h5 class="postheading"> <%# Eval("BusinessName")%></h5>
                        <p class="postadd"><%# Eval("OfficeAddress")%> </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="postifoback">
                        <p class="postadd"><%# Eval("BusinessDetails")%></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="posts-left sngl-img" style="padding-left:5px;">
                                                 <asp:Image runat="server" ID="imgProfile" src='<%# Eval("CompanyLogoPath") %>'  height="110px" width="180px"  alt="" class="img-responsive" />                         
                    </div>
                    <div class="posts-right">
                        <p ><b><%# Eval("BusinessType")%></b></p>                           
                        <p><%# Eval("Others")%></p>
                                                <p>                                                             
                                                             <button type="button" id="btnContact"   onclick='openPopup("<%# Eval("BusinessContactNo")%>","<%# Eval("Email")%>","<%# Eval("Website")%>")' class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                                                                    View Contact
                                                                </button>     
                                                             <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick='openPopup1("<%# Eval("UserId")%>")' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@mdo">Visitor Popup</button>
                                                        </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                </div>
                                    <div class="clearfix"> </div>
            </div>      
                 </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>//business details grid

popup-
 <!-- Modal to save visitors details -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" >
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
             <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Enter Details</h4>
                    </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                        <form>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">BusinessId:</label>
                                 <label id="lblUserId" ></label>

                            </div>
                             <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Name:</label>
                                 <asp:TextBox ID="txtVisitorname" class="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" class="form-control" runat="server" style="display:none"></asp:TextBox>               
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                 <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Mobile:</label>
                                 <asp:TextBox ID="txtVisitormob" class="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>               
                             </div>
                     </form>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                     <asp:ImageButton ID="btnSaveVisitor"  runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("UserId") %>'  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" OnClick="btnSaveVisitor_Click" BorderWidth="0" ImageUrl="~/img/ExpressInterest.png"  />
                    </div>
                </div>
      </div>
    </div>//save visitor  popup


       <!-- Modal to view contact details -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Business Contact Details</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
             <p>
            Business Contact:
            <label id="lblId">
            </label>
                 <%--<span id="lblId"></span>--%>
            <br />
            Email:
            <label id="lblName">
            </label>
            <br />
            Website:
            <label id="lblPrice">
            </label>

          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>//contact details popup

.cs code-
    private void LoadMembers()
            {
                 try
                    {
                         List<Business> members = new List<Business>();
                        members = new SearchHelper().GetEntireList();
                        gvMemberList.DataSource = members;
                        gvMemberList.DataBind();
                         Session["lstProfiles"] = members;
                 }
                 catch
                 {
                }
             }//load all business data in grid

           protected void btnSaveVisitor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
           {
               try
               {
                   string userID = ((ImageButton)sender).CommandArgument;           
                   Business business = ReadVisitorForm();
                   business = new BusinessHelper().SaveVisitor(business);
                   if (business.ID > 0 && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(business.UserId))
                   {


                       litInfoMessage.Text = string.Format(@"<div class='success'>visitor saved <b>{0}</b>.<br/></div>");
                       ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myModal", "openPopup(BusinessContactNo,Email,Website);", true);


                   }
                   else
                   {
                       litInfoMessage.Text = "<div class='error'>Oops! Registration failed. </div>";
                   }
               }
               catch (Exception ex)
               {
                   //MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
               }

           }//to save visiotrs data and display contact details 
           private Business ReadVisitorForm()
           {
               Business b = new Business

               {
                   UserId = TextBox1.Text.Trim(),           
                   VisitorName = txtVisitorname.Text.Trim(),
                   VisitorMobile = txtVisitormob.Text.Trim()           
                   //UserId=lblUserId.Text.Trim()
               };

               return b;
           }
```

Comment: I have two tables BusinessDirectory and BusinessDirectoryVisitor.In the grid view i have display some data form  BusinessDirectory table to view other data user has to click on view contact button when he clicks popup will appear which takes users name and mobile then this info with business id will save in the BusinessDirectoryVisitor and display another popup with other business details from BusinessDirectory  table How to do that please help me to solve this problem

Comment: please consider giving some details on what you want to achieve. so far you just posted a big blob of code

Comment: I have add the image with description please check and help me to solve this issues

Comment: You cannot post the data to database from JS directly. If you do that, it will require posting that form. So, your original popup will refresh, after which you can redirect to new popup.

Comment: what is the solution to achieve this functionality